# Drupal S3fs plugin: Some Private files are giving 404 not found error. How can I enable to show them?

Tags: drupal

I am using Drupal S3fs plugin: In this, some Private files are giving 404 not found error. How can I enable to show them?

These files are exists on s3 and file_managed tables also. I have older database table 's3fs_file' backup, do I need to insert into this table for display private images.

Example: URL/system/files/FileName.  showing 404 when try to access.

Can any one know where I can put these files name to these will access as private to file owner.

Thank you for your prompt help in advance.